# Adding to an Object Angular 2

Tags: angular, object

I have an object in my app that starts out as:

```
var myObj = {};
```

The user enters in some values, and I want to "push" their values to the object.  So when they enter in some values, I want it to be:

```
myObj = {{item1:"value1",item2:"value2"}};
```

If they enter in some more values, I want the array to be:

```
myObj = {{item1:"newValue1",item2:"newValue2"},{item1:"value1",item2:"value2"}}
```

And so on and so forth.  I tried it using this code:

```
var newObject = Object.assign({}, myObj, {item1:userValue1,item2:userValue2});
myObj = newObject;
```

But this alway overwrites whatever is already in there.  I'm sure I'm not headed in the right direction, but I'm not sure how to proceed.  As a second question, I am trying to then show this new Object in a table using *ngFor, so I use a custom pipe to change it into an array:

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

How do I show this in a table?

Comment: u can't push object to object

Comment: I think you are mistaking Objects with Arrays. Also `myObj = {{item1:"value1",item2:"value2"}};` is invalid syntax.

Comment: An array is defined with `[ ]`, not with `{ }`. You can use `myArray.push(item)` to add new items to it.

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka I know, I'm trying to find a way to do what push does for arrays.  My code doesn't use push at all, just to give an idea of what I am trying to do.

Comment: What makes you think you think you need the user inputs to be in an object, and then need to use a pipe, which isn't the correct use of a pipe, to transform the object of inputs into an array, rather than just using an array?

Comment: @ConnorsFan I can't use arrays, I have to use an object as I am getting a map object from the backend.

Comment: @JunKang It's what is coming from the backend.

Comment: If you want to add to an object, you must give a property name to each item: `myObj.firstItem = { some data }; myObj.secondItem = { other data };`. Or `myObj[propName] = { some data }`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign to set some key-value pairs to an object, this is the basic simple Javascript syntax :

```
var a = {};
a["myKey1"] = "myValue1";
a["myKey2"] = "myValue2";


console.log(a); // {myKey1: "myValue1", myKey2: "myValue2"}
```

no need to have any special "push" method or so.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way using `push`

```
var obj = {};

if(some valid condition){
    obj.push({item : 'value'});
}
```

You can maybe wrap this inside a loop if that is what you are looking for.

Your  `myObj = {{item1:"newValue1",item2:"newValue2"},{item1:"value1",item2:"value2"}}` is actually adding an `Object`. Do you want to add an `Object` or `Array` or `Array of Objects`?